# EF CORE include() not in the intellisense

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a repository project with abstract class using EF CORE to get data for the depending MVC project.  In the repository the include() method show up in the intellisense after .Set() in the repository, but not in the MVC project's controllers.  How do I make the include() available to the controller?  Thanks.

```js
public abstract class RepositoryBase < T >: IRepositoryBase < T > where T: class {
  protected PCC_FITContext RepositoryContext {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public RepositoryBase(PCC_FITContext repositoryContext) {
    this.RepositoryContext = repositoryContext;
  }

  public IQueryable < T > FindAll() {
    return this.RepositoryContext.Set < T > ().AsNoTracking();
  }

  public IQueryable < T > FindByCondition(Expression < Func < T, bool >> expression) {
    return this.RepositoryContext.Set < T > ().Where(expression).AsNoTracking();
  }
  
  .........
  .........
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the drawbacks of EF Core `Include` / `ThenInclude` pattern. These are EF Core specific extension methods defined in [EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-3.1) class which is part of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` assembly (package).

So in order to have access to them, (1) the project must have (package) reference to [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/) package and (2) the code file needs

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```